# Create a Java swing / awt Layout with JLabels of different heights

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

I hava a JLabel (lets call it main) and during Runtime I am adding multiple JLabels to it. Sometimes these JLabels contain an Image, sometimes a JTextArea. The Problem is, because of the different Content they have different sizes. As long as I only add Text the layout is like I want it, just the size of the text. But if I add the first JLabel with an Image as content every JLabel I already added increases its height to the one from the JLabel containing the image.

My question is, which Layout should I use for the main JLabel and how should I add the other JLabeles which I add during runtime?

I first tried the GridLayout and now have the BorderLayout but not like I want it to.

Comment: Try the `BoxLayout` or `GridBagLayout`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples to get you started. Also, you can nest panels with different layout managers to achieve your desired layout.

Comment: Thank you very much @camickr , works fine so war. Maybe one follow up question: If I add JTextAreas to this main JPanel, which has the border layout they are perfectly aligned to the left and filling up the window till the end. But the JLabels which contain my images are always added to the center, also when I add SwingConstant.left to the "add" method? Any Ideas why? I already put like 3 hours in finding a solution.

Comment: The BorderLayout will resize components to fill the space available. The default for a JLabel is to paint itself in the CENTER of the available space. Read the JLabel API there are method to control the horizontal positioning of the text/icon within the label. When you ask a question in the future post a proper [mcve] demonstrating the problem.